# Too many hostnames error when deploying resoures to a resource group in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have created and configured resources in a dev resource group in Azure. This includes storage accounts and azure apps and app insights.

Then I went ahead and extracted the arm template for the resource group and the corresponding parameter file.

I then tried to deploy the template with the modified parameter file for the new resource group but no matter what I have tried I always get this error:

```
} undefined
2019-02-19T10:17:59.7469744Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "Too many (2) hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is 1.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "Too many (2) hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is 1."
    },
    {
      "Code": "BadRequest"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "ExtendedCode": "04017",
        "MessageTemplate": "Too many ({0}) hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is {1}.",
        "Parameters": [
          "2",
          "1"
        ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "Too many (2) hostnames in the default DNS zone. Limit is 1."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
} undefined
```

There is one issue on github not answers and very little information on this error. Anyone knows what this could be related too?

ARM template viewable here:
https://paste.ee/p/TxgvY

Comment: i suspect you have too many hostnames in the default dns zone... show your template?

Comment: @4c74356b41, it seems to be too big to post here. Hit a limitation with amount of text that can be sent. Any chance we can take it up in a chat?

Comment: just upload to some paste.ee and give a link

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/TxgvY

Comment: why do you need `hostNameBindings` in the template?

Comment: well, it was part of the template when I extracted it from the dev resource group. Should the template be "cleaned" from the hostNameBindings? I am assuming they are for binding the urls defined in the parameter to the two apps?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by removing hostbindings, comments, and the alert parts as well.